# Is it possible to start python thread from inside Vim under HP-UX?

Tags: python, vim, hp-ux

I've compiled Python 2.7.10 and Vim 7.4 with Python support (HP-UX 11.31 ia64).
Everything seems to be working well except for threads. Here's simple example.

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def threaded_function(arg):
    for i in range(arg):
        print i
        sleep(1)

def start_thread():
    thread = Thread(target = threaded_function, args=(5, ))
    thread.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_thread()
```

Python interpreter executes it perfectly well.

```
% python thread.py
0
1
2
3
4
```

But Vim produces an error when I'm trying to source it (enclosed in python << EOF / EOF brackets):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 11, in start_thread
  File "/home/users/zemtsoe/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 745, in start
    _start_new_thread(self.__bootstrap, ())
thread.error: can't start new thread
```

AFAIK Python threads are available (despite Vim thread-unsafety).
Also I'm unable to use YCM plugin because of this error.
What can I do?

Comment: So you're running the above script from inside Vim? Or outside Vim (ie. as `python thread_test.py`)?

Comment: You seem to have logged in to two different accounts. Merge them.